# Return correct array from closure

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, closures, laravelcollective

I use on my code a closure with SSH of [LaravelCollective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/ssh#basic-usage) on Laravel 5.3

But my surpise it's when try return exit for any commands, get a truncate result.

```
$exit = array();
SSH::run($cmd, function ($line) use (&$exit) {
    echo $line.PHP_EOL;
    $exit[] = $line; 
});
dd($exit) // dd it's a var_dump + exit helper on Laravel
```

Well this code return a first part (echo $line.PHP_EOL) correct such below

```
/Volumes/MACBACKUP/cprsync_remote/hq/daily/users/tamainut/home
/Volumes/MACBACKUP/cprsync_remote/hq/daily/users/tamainut/home/daily.0
/Volumes/MACBACKUP/cprsync_remote/hq/daily/users/tamainut/home/daily.0/.appdata
/Volumes/MACBACKUP/cprsync_remote/hq/daily/users/tamainut/home/daily.0/.autorespond
/Volumes/MACBACKUP/cprsync_remote/hq/daily/users/tamainut/home/daily.0/.cpanel
/Volumes/MACBACKUP/cprsync_remote/hq/daily/users/tamainut/home/daily.0/.cphorde
/Volumes/MACBACKUP/cprsync_remote/hq/daily/users/tamainut/home/daily.0/.cpremote
/Volumes/MACBACKUP/cprsync_remote/hq/daily/users/tamainut/home/daily.0/.elinks
...
```

And wrong result on array. 4

```
array:5 [
  0 => """
    /Volumes/MACBACKUP/cprsync_remote/hq/daily/users/tamainut/home\n
    /Volumes/MACBACKUP/cprsync_remote/hq/daily/users/tamainut/home/daily.0\n
    /Volumes/MACBAC
    ...
    """
  4 => """
    UP/cprsync_remote/hq/daily/users/tamainut/home/daily.8/tmp\n
  /Volumes/MACBACKUP/cprsync_remote/hq/daily/users/tamainut/home/daily.8/updates\n
    /Volumes/MACBACKUP/cprsync_remote/hq/daily/users/tamainut/home/daily.9\n
    /Volumes/MACBACKUP/cprsync_r
```

I try several options but any work fine.

I don't understand why i see perfect echo lines, but can't insert on array for work more later.

EDIT after some comments.

I see that problem it's closure, get a `line`of SSH command how string with "\n". After get max size for string truncate, and run a new iteration of closure. That it's problem.

Comment: Don't you mean to do `dd($exit);` at the end, to see the full array of all lines you stored?

Comment: I use only dd for see values on $exit.

Comment: I realize that. But your array is `$exit`;

Comment: Ok... sorry for typing error.Question it's not dd(). dd() it's a helper. forget dd() and think about value of $exit.

Comment: I'm very much aware of how `dd()` works. And you need to `dd($exit)` to debug and view the value of `$exit`!

Comment: Ok. If you know dd... you can read perfectly my post. Now I had edited for more explain problem, derived of SSH closure. Thanks.

Comment: abrkim, can you fix the typo in your paste above ... `$line` isn't even in the same scope as the `dd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests I have found a solution that although it does not seem very appropriate works.

The problem is that the SSH run method, returns as many string as necessary, for a byte limit, which I do not know.

We can not use an array, since the array would contain truncated elements, so the best thing in my opinion is to extract the line as a string and treat it later.

If someone can reply with a most grateful response,

```
$exit = '';
SSH::run($cmd, function ($line) use (&$exit) {
   $exit = $exit.$line;
});
$arr = explode("\n",$exit);
dd($arr);
```

Show correct result

```
array:863 [
  0 => "/Volumes/MACBACKUP/cprsync_remote/hq/daily/users/tamainut/home"
  1 => "/Volumes/MACBACKUP/cprsync_remote/hq/daily/users/tamainut/home/daily.0"
  2 => "/Volumes/MACBACKUP/cprsync_remote/hq/daily/users/tamainut/home/daily.0/.appdata"
...

 861 => "/Volumes/MACBACKUP/cprsync_remote/hq/daily/users/tamainut/home/daily.9/updates"
  862 => ""
]
```

Attention to limit of string (2GB but other limitations imposes by `memory_limit`)